# Creating output file in C++ Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, file, output

I have a C++ project which I initially compiled with g++. Now, I am trying to make it work in Visual Studio 2010 and the problem is that the regular commands that create an empty output file for writing:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ofstream fout("afile.txt");
fout<<"write someting"<<endl;
fout.close();
```

will not work in VS2010 (no file is created). Even if the file already exists nothing is written on it.

So, any ideas what is the correct way of opening a file for writing from C++ in VS2010 ?

Comment: I have to ask, but are you sure you're looking in the right directory?  How are you running the app in the debugger - do you specify a working directory?

Comment: Definitely works - creates a file with "write someting" in it I just compiled and ran just in case...

Comment: Your code is correct. You're not looking in the right place, or you're trying to write somewhere you don't have permissions to write.

Comment: I have looked everywhere under the project directory and still cannot file any generated file.

Comment: you can uncheck the "Hide extensions for known file type" in the Windows Explorer View settings and then search for "afile.txt"

Comment: You can try a full path like "D:\\afile.txt" first to see if you were searching the wrong place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suspicion is that the file is created somewhere other than you expected - Check out where the working directory is pointing. This is 2012, but it is very similar if not the same... Right click on the project in vs2010, and select properties, Then select debugging and look at the working directory:

[image]

Alternitively, build it, and copy the app to a directory you create - Then run it on the command line to check whether its a permissions problem.

Answer (score 1):

Following code works fine by me:

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    ofstream fout("afile.txt");
    fout << "write someting"<<endl;
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

You didn't use the main method (strange that it didn't give any syntax errors).
Make sure when you creat a project like this it is a ConsoleApplication and it's an empty project (you can check this option under "Additional Options" in the Win32 Application Wizard (The wizard used to create a project).

Standard C++ should work in Visual Studio. If you want to be sure you're using only standard C++ code, you can always use the /Za compiler option (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx)

Comment: OP says it was working before with g++. I think he simplified a little too much.

Answer (score -1):

manually add afile.txt into the same location with your source file, and then run the your program. text will be written into the file. But make sure afile.txt file is not open when you run the program

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem which puzzled me for a few minutes. Examine your project directory. I bet you will find your file in there. If not, then you need to specify a working directory for either debug or release modes. In MS Visual Studio you can do so by clicking the Properties on the Project menu and then specifying in the Configuration properties in lets say a Debugging tab in the Working directory field the directory from which you want your project to be launched.